# How to capitalize first letter of each word in a string and change all spaces to underscores in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to implement a function in JavaScript that gives me an output like this for a given input value

Input: `stack overflow`

Output: `Stack_Overflow`

Input: `the big bang theory`

Output: `The_Big_Bang_Theory`

I have written the code to capitalize the letters but cannot seem to figure how to call both the functions on the same input at the same time. I am relatively new to Javascript and any help would be greatly appreciated. I will share my code here for further clarity

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="" size="50" />

<pre id="myOutput" type="myInput">type something in the box above</pre>

<script>

String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
return this.toLowerCase().replace( /\b\w/g, function (m) {

return m.toUpperCase();

});
};

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(){
if(!search || !replace){return this;}
return this.replace(/ /g,"_"), function (n){
return n;
});
};

var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

var myOutput = document.getElementById('myOutput')

myInput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
myOutput.innerHTML = this.value.capitalize();


});

myInput.addEventListener('input', function(f)) {
myOutput.innerHTML = this.value.replaceAll();
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `replaceAll` function is weird.

Comment: for capitalize, check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript). For space to underscore, try `value = element.value.replace(/\s+/, '_')`

Comment: You should indent your JS code, it will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually passing in any arguments to the `capitalize` function. I've edited your code slightly to accommodate this.

```
// first check to see if `capitalize` doesn't
// already exist on the prototype - don't go overwriting
// native methods :)
if (!('capitalize' in String.prototype)) {
  String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, function(m) {
      return m.toUpperCase();
    });
  };
}

if (!('replaceAll' in String.prototype)) {

  // pass in search and replace as arguments
  String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace) {
    if (!search || !replace) return this;

    // then just do a replace using the arguments
    return this.replace(search, replace, 'g');
  };
}

var str = 'the big bang theory';
str.capitalize().replaceAll(' ', '_'); // The_Big_Bang_Theory
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/s8L6nkyz/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
var str = 'stack overflow';
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
str= str.replace(' ','_');
alert(str);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n6nqpwe6/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I've embedded the method (called `capitalize` as you do) in the String class and placed the code in a running demo:

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
  return this.toLowerCase().replace(
     /\b(\w)(\w*)( *)/g, 
     function(all, f, r, s) { return f.toUpperCase() + (r?r:'') + (s?'_':''); }
  );
};
 
var tests = ['stAck oVerFlow','the bIg bANg theory'];

while(t = tests.pop()){ 
    console.log(t, ' -> ', t.capitalize());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

**Legenda**

The regex uses the capturing groups to match:

- `\b(\w)`: the first char of a regex word (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). I does not use `[a-z]` to matches also the spaces after words already starts with a capital letter or numbers (or underscore, do you want to avoid this?).
- `(\w*)`: the rest of the regex word
- `( *)`: one or more spaces

Then in the closure it capitalize the first letter, append the rest of the word (if present) and append an underscore '_' if there are actually one or more spaces after the word.